# Simple NSButton Hiding Another NSButton

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, button, nsbutton

I have 2 NSButtons, Both IBActions.  When I click one of the buttons, I want the other button to be hidden.  I can make them Hide themselves, but I can't figure out how to hide the other one.  My actual implementation for this is to have a 'start' button, that is hidden until the user is finished doing some tasks, then shows up again with the other objects being hidden.

Thanks for your help!

```
@interface Label : NSObject 
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
}

-(IBAction)btnTest1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnTest2:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)btnTest1:(id)sender
{
    myTextField.stringValue = @"You selected the 1st Button";

    NSButton *tempButton = sender;
    [tempButton setHidden:YES];
}

-(IBAction)btnTest2:(id)sender
{
    myTextField.stringValue = @"You selected the 2nd Button";

    NSButton *tempButton = sender;
    [tempButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface Label : NSObject 
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
    IBOutlet NSButton *btn1;
    IBOutlet NSButton *btn2;
}
```

in method : `[btn1 setHidden: YES]` for btn2 the same.

Comment: I knew it was simple.  I didn't realize you could have both an IBAction and IBOutlet for the same object.  Thanks!